# How to avoid Edge overlap when having two self loops Edges for the same Node

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I have this issue when using the Vis.js library.

I am trying to create one node with two self-loop edges.
The issue is that the edges overlap and the labels are not readable.

I have tried changing some physics parameters but had no luck with it.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

```
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},

]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 1, label: "0"},
    {from: 1, to: 1, label: "1"}


]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

// provide the data in the vis format
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {physics:{enabled:true}};

// initialize your network!
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

As you can see from the image result, the labels overlap:
https://ibb.co/gmT8v8q

Do you have any solutions for this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Try the angle parameter in selfReferences property of Edges. It will create multiple self edges at different angle of the node circle.

```
    var data = {
nodes:
    [
        {id:1, label: "Entity 1", shape: 'circle'},

    ],
edges:
    [
        {"from":1,"to":1,"arrows":"to","label":"Prg", 
        selfReference:{
        size: 20,
        angle: Math.PI / 4,
        renderBehindTheNode: true
            } 
        },
        {"from":1,"to":1,"arrows":"to","label":"Boot", selfReference:{
        size: 20,
        angle: Math.PI / 1,
        renderBehindTheNode: true
            } },

    ]};
```

Comment: This solution makes sense, but it doesn't seem to work in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/majosahewe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Woops, was just using an outdated vis-network version. With the newest one, it works: https://jsbin.com/zoginokupi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Velu's solution works great. Just wanted to add that changing the top-level `selfReferenceSize` param should also do the trick:

```js
// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

// provide the data in the vis format
var data = {
  nodes:
  [
    {id:1, label: "Entity 1", shape: 'circle'},

  ],
  edges:
  [
    {
      "from":1,"to":1,"arrows":"to","label":"Edge 1",
      selfReferenceSize: 50
    },
    {
      "from": 1, "to": 1, "arrows": "to", "label": "Edge 2",
      selfReferenceSize: 20
    }
  ]
};

var options = {physics:{enabled:true}};

// initialize your network!
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

[image]